# How to calculate the angle of 2 lines in excel

Tags: excel, angle, degrees

For each Value displayed in an excel 'line chart', I want to calculate in excel the degrees between

- a vertical 180% line and
- the angle of the line created for that 'Value'.

| Pt (x) | Value (y) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 15 |
| 3 | 40 |

[Sample display in this link with the degrees desired represented by the purple arrows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRXKc.png)

I have tried DEGREES ATAN SLOPE but not doing something correctly

Does anyone know the formula for this in excel?

Comment: Welcome to SO., I don't think there is a specific formula. This looks like more a Pythagorean theorem. If you have all the points, you can calculate the measure of each side of a right triangle. If you have the 3 sides, then you can calculate all angles using sin or cos.

Comment: Can you show what you tried until now?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a good candidate for your formula:

```
=DEGREES(PI()/2 - ATAN(SLOPE(B2:B3,A2:A3)))
```

Hereby a screenshot:

[image]

Be aware that both X- and Y-scales should be equal or very similar in order to get good results: in your drawing, the distance between 1 and 2 on the X-axis is far larger than the distance between 0 and 5 on the Y-axis, giving a completely wrong impression for the angle.

Comment: Thank you. I see what you mean about the axis.
My objective is to identify if the first point is above a defined 'baseline' incline. 
The degree amounts don't matter too much after that aside is it getting steeper from the original baseline or not. I don't know if this helps.